# Flutter Android - Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission

Tags: android, flutter

I have a problem: I wanted to create a simple code that reads the values from the gamepad and displays the position of the joystick or the pressed button on the phone screen. A RAW stream would be enough for me.
I've been struggling with this for another week and with no results, I keep getting the message about android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
I have an A53 phone with Android14 and a 9083S gamepad.
Is there any way to read the joystick position or button status normally?

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'bluetooth_service.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BLE Data Receiver',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _bluetoothService = MyBluetoothService();
  String _data = 'Connected. Waiting for data...';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _requestPermissions().then((_) => _connectToGamepad());
  }

Future<void> _requestPermissions() async {
  var scanStatus = await Permission.bluetoothScan.request();
  var connectStatus = await Permission.bluetoothConnect.request();

  if (scanStatus != PermissionStatus.granted || connectStatus != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Bluetooth Permissions Required'),
        content: Text('This app requires permissions to scan and connect to Bluetooth devices for proper functioning. Please grant these permissions.'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Cancel'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(), 
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Settings'),
            onPressed: () {
              openAppSettings(); 
              Navigator.of(context).pop(); 
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _bluetoothService.disconnectFromDevice();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _connectToGamepad() async {
    var scanStatus = await Permission.bluetoothScan.status;
    var connectStatus = await Permission.bluetoothConnect.status;

    if (scanStatus.isGranted && connectStatus.isGranted) {
      if (_bluetoothService.isConnected()) {
        await _bluetoothService.disconnectFromDevice();
      }

      await _bluetoothService.startScanning(const Duration(seconds: 10));
      if (_bluetoothService.isConnected()) {
        _bluetoothService.stream.listen((dataList) {
          setState(() {
            _data = dataList.join('\n');
          });
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _data = 'Unable to connect to the device.';
        });
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _data = 'Missing required Bluetooth permissions.';
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BLE Data Receiver'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(_data),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

bluetooth_service.dart:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_blue_plus/flutter_blue_plus.dart';

class MyBluetoothService {
  StreamSubscription? _scanSubscription;
  StreamSubscription? _deviceConnection;
  StreamSubscription? _characteristicSubscription;
  BluetoothDevice? _connectedDevice;
  final StreamController<List<int>> _dataController = StreamController<List<int>>.broadcast();

  Stream<List<int>> get stream => _dataController.stream;

  Future<void> startScanning(Duration timeout) async {
    String deviceName = "PG-9083S";
    FlutterBluePlus.startScan(timeout: timeout);

    _scanSubscription = FlutterBluePlus.scanResults.listen((results) {
      for (ScanResult result in results) {
        print('Device found: ${result.device.platformName}');
        if (result.device.platformName == deviceName || result.advertisementData.advName == deviceName) {
          _connectToDevice(result.device);
          FlutterBluePlus.stopScan();
          break;
        }
      }
    });

    await Future.delayed(timeout, () => FlutterBluePlus.stopScan());
  }

  Future<void> _connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) async {
    try {
      await device.connect();
      _connectedDevice = device;
      _deviceConnection = device.connectionState.listen((state) {
        print('Connection state: $state');
        if (state == BluetoothConnectionState.connected) {
          _discoverServices();
        } else if (state == BluetoothConnectionState.disconnected) {
          print('Device disconnected');
        }
      });
      await _scanSubscription?.cancel();
      _scanSubscription = null;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error connecting: $e');
      rethrow;
    }
  }

Future<void> _discoverServices() async {
  if (_connectedDevice == null) return;

  var services = await _connectedDevice!.discoverServices();
  for (var service in services) {
    if (service.uuid == Guid('00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')) {
      for (var characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if (characteristic.uuid == Guid('00002A4D-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb')) {
          if (characteristic.properties.notify) {
            await _subscribeToCharacteristic(characteristic);
          } else {
            print('Characteristic does not support notifications.');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


  Future<void> _subscribeToCharacteristic(BluetoothCharacteristic characteristic) async {
    if (!characteristic.properties.notify) {
      print('Characteristic does not support notifications.');
      return;
    }
    
    await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
    _characteristicSubscription = characteristic.lastValueStream.listen((value) {
      print('Data received: $value');
      _dataController.add(value);
    });
  }

  Future<void> disconnectFromDevice() async {
    await _characteristicSubscription?.cancel();
    await _deviceConnection?.cancel();
    if (_connectedDevice != null) {
      await _connectedDevice!.disconnect();
      _connectedDevice = null;
    }
    _dataController.close();
  }

  bool isConnected() {
    return _connectedDevice != null && _connectedDevice!.connectionState == BluetoothConnectionState.connected;
  }
}
```

manifest:

```xml
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />

<!-- New Bluetooth permissions in Android 12
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<!-- legacy for Android 11 or lower -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>

<!-- legacy for Android 9 or lower -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
```

Below is the full log:

```
PS C:\Users\backu\OneDrive\Dokumenty\GitHub\gammepad_ipega> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on SM A536B in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6,2s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...           7,8s
Syncing files to device SM A536B...                                 93ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

A Dart VM Service on SM A536B is available at: http://127.0.0.1:56067/PgGpN7OntoE=/
I/BLASTBufferQueue_Java(32173): update, w= 1080 h= 2400 mName = ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity] mNativeObject= 0xb400006fb4a702b0 sc.mNativeObject= 0xb400006ed4a64d10 format= -3 caller= android.view.ViewRootImpl.updateBlastSurfaceIfNeeded:2968 android.view.ViewRootImpl.relayoutWindow:9998 android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4056 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:3239 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:11197 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1650
I/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): Relayout returned: old=(0,0,1080,2400) new=(0,0,1080,2400) req=(1080,2400)0 dur=6 res=0x401 s={true 0xb400006fe4abc4a0} ch=false seqId=0
I/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): updateBoundsLayer: t=android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@aabc3fb sc=Surface(name=Bounds for - com.example.gammepad_ipega/com.example.gammepad_ipega.MainActivity@0)/@0xffb1c18 frame=1
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): reportNextDraw android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4658 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:3239 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:11197 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1650 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1659
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on SM A536B is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9104?uri=http://127.0.0.1:56067/PgGpN7OntoE=/
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: flutterHotRestart
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] initializing BluetoothAdapter
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(32173): Compat change id reported: 263076149; UID 10490; state: DISABLED
I/BLASTBufferQueue(32173): [SurfaceView[com.example.gammepad_ipega/com.example.gammepad_ipega.MainActivity]@0#1](f:0,a:0,s:0) onFrameAvailable the first frame is available
I/BluetoothAdapter(32173): BluetoothAdapter() : com.example.gammepad_ipega
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
I/BluetoothAdapter(32173): BLE support array set: [true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] disconnectAllDevices(flutterHotRestart)
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] connectedPeripherals: 0
D/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): 71140718 setAlpha: alpha=1.0
I/SurfaceView(32173): 71140718 Changes: creating=false format=false size=false visible=false alpha=true hint=false visible=false left=false top=false z=false attached=true lifecycleStrategy=false
I/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): 71140718 Cur surface: Surface(name=null)/@0x417992c
I/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): updateSurface: mVisible = true mSurface.isValid() = true
I/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): updateSurface: mSurfaceCreated = true surfaceChanged = false visibleChanged = false
I/SurfaceView(32173): 71140718 surfaceRedrawNeeded
I/SurfaceView(32173): 71140718 finishedDrawing
V/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): Layout: x=0 y=0 w=1080 h=2274, frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2274)
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: startScan
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): semIsBleEnabled(): ON
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(32173): Start Scan with callback
D/BluetoothLeScanner(32173): onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=13 mScannerId=0
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): Setup new sync=wmsSync-ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity]#2
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): Creating new active sync group ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity]#3
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): registerCallbacksForSync syncBuffer=false
D/SurfaceView(32173): 71140718 updateSurfacePosition RenderWorker, frameNr = 1, position = [0, 0, 1080, 2274] surfaceSize = 1080x2274
I/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): uSP: rtp = Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2274) rtsw = 1080 rtsh = 2274
I/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): onSSPAndSRT: pl = 0 pt = 0 sx = 1.0 sy = 1.0
I/SurfaceView@43d856e(32173): aOrMT: ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity] t = android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@6c9a55c fN = 1 android.view.SurfaceView.-$$Nest$mapplyOrMergeTransaction:0 android.view.SurfaceView$SurfaceViewPositionUpdateListener.positionChanged:1660 android.graphics.RenderNode$CompositePositionUpdateListener.positionChanged:369
I/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): mWNT: t=0xb400006e64a71250 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400006fb4a702b0 fn= 1 caller= android.view.SurfaceView.applyOrMergeTransaction:1592 android.view.SurfaceView.-$$Nest$mapplyOrMergeTransaction:0 android.view.SurfaceView$SurfaceViewPositionUpdateListener.positionChanged:1660
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): Received frameDrawingCallback syncResult=0 frameNum=1.
I/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): mWNT: t=0xb400006e64a71930 mBlastBufferQueue=0xb400006fb4a702b0 fn= 1 caller= android.view.ViewRootImpl$8.onFrameDraw:13614 android.view.ThreadedRenderer$1.onFrameDraw:788 <bottom of call stack>
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): Setting up sync and frameCommitCallback
I/BLASTBufferQueue(32173): [ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity]#0](f:0,a:0,s:0) onFrameAvailable the first frame is available
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): Received frameCommittedCallback lastAttemptedDrawFrameNum=1 didProduceBuffer=true
D/OpenGLRenderer(32173): CFMS:: SetUp Pid : 32173    Tid : 32199
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): reportDrawFinished
I/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): registerCallbackForPendingTransactions
I/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 0
D/ViewRootImpl@e4c261e[MainActivity](32173): mThreadedRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 0xb400006fe4abc4a0}
D/InputMethodManagerUtils(32173): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager(32173): startInputInner - IInputMethodManagerGlobalInvoker.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputMethodManagerUtils(32173): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/BluetoothAdapter(32173): BluetoothAdapter() : com.example.gammepad_ipega
D/InsetsController(32173): onStateChanged: host=com.example.gammepad_ipega/com.example.gammepad_ipega.MainActivity from=android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessageImpl:7085 state=InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mDisplayCutout=DisplayCutout{insets=Rect(0, 88 - 0, 0) waterfall=Insets{left=0, top=0, right=0, bottom=0} boundingRect={Bounds=[Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(512, 0 - 568, 88), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0), Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0)]} cutoutPathParserInfo={CutoutPathParserInfo{displayWidth=1080 displayHeight=2400 physicalDisplayWidth=1080 physicalDisplayHeight=2400 density={2.8125} cutoutSpec={M 0,0 M 0,11.43427858034597 a 9.899054752987353,9.899054752987353 0 1,0 0,19.79810950597471 a 9.899054752987353,9.899054752987353 0 1,0 0,-19.79810950597471 Z @dp} rotation={0} scale={1.0} physicalPixelDisplaySizeRatio={1.0}}}}, mRoundedCorners=RoundedCorners{[RoundedCorner{position=TopLeft, radius=0, center=Point(0, 0)}, RoundedCorner{position=TopRight, radius=0, center=Point(0, 0)}, RoundedCorner{position=BottomRight, radius=0, center=Point(0, 0)}, RoundedCorner{position=BottomLeft, radius=0, 
center=Point(0, 0)}]}  mRoundedCornerFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400), mPrivacyIndicatorBounds=PrivacyIndicatorBounds {static bounds=Rect(964, 0 - 1080, 88) rotation=0}, mDisplayShape=DisplayShape{ spec=-1893857183 displayWidth=1080 displayHeight=2400 physicalPixelDisplaySizeRatio=1.0 rotation=0 offsetX=0 offsetY=0 scale=1.0}, mSources= { InsetsSource: {3 mType=ime mFrame=[0,0][0,0] mVisible=false mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {27 mType=displayCutout mFrame=[0,0][1080,88] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {187a0001 mType=navigationBars mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {187a0004 mType=systemGestures mFrame=[0,0][0,0] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {187a0005 mType=mandatorySystemGestures mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {187a0006 mType=tappableElement mFrame=[0,2274][1080,2400] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {187a0024 mType=systemGestures mFrame=[0,0][0,0] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {790d0000 mType=statusBars mFrame=[0,0][1080,88] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {790d0005 mType=mandatorySystemGestures mFrame=[0,0][1080,120] mVisible=true mFlags=[]}, InsetsSource: {790d0006 mType=tappableElement mFrame=[0,0][1080,88] mVisible=true mFlags=[]} }
D/InsetsSourceConsumer(32173): applyRequestedVisibilityToControl: visible=false, type=8
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie: 
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie: 
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie:
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie:
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie:
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie:
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie: 
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie: 
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie:
I/flutter (32173): Znaleziono urządzenie: PG-9083S
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: stopScan
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
D/BluetoothLeScanner(32173): Stop Scan with callback
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: connect
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(32173): Compat change id reported: 265103382; UID 10490; state: DISABLED
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): connect() - device: 01:34:08:20:58:A8, auto: false
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): registerApp()
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): registerApp() - UUID=5a97c55b-457a-45f1-8e3a-a36ac25d9488
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: getAdapterState
D/BluetoothAdapter(32173): getBleEnabledArray(): ON
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=XX:XX:XX:XX:58:A8
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onConnectionStateChange:connected
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   status: SUCCESS
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): onConnectionUpdated() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:58:A8 interval=6 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: requestMtu
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): configureMTU() - device: 01:34:08:20:58:A8 mtu: 512
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): onConfigureMTU() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:58:A8 mtu=196 status=0
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMtuChanged:
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   mtu: 196
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   status: GATT_SUCCESS (0)
I/flutter (32173): Stan połączenia: BluetoothConnectionState.connected
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: discoverServices
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): discoverServices() - device: 01:34:08:20:58:A8
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): onSearchComplete() = Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:58:A8 Status=0
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onServicesDiscovered:
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   count: 6
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   status: 0GATT_SUCCESS
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): onConnectionUpdated() - Device=XX:XX:XX:XX:58:A8 interval=36 latency=0 timeout=500 status=0
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: setNotifyValue
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onDescriptorWrite:
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   chr: 2a05
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   desc: 2902
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP]   status: GATT_SUCCESS (0)
D/[FBP-Android](32173): [FBP] onMethodCall: setNotifyValue
D/BluetoothGatt(32173): setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a4d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
E/flutter (32173): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(androidException, java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10490 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED., java.lang.SecurityException: Need BLUETOOTH PRIVILEGED permission: Neither user 10490 nor current process has android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED.
E/flutter (32173):      at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:2418)
E/flutter (32173):      at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:2446)
E/flutter (32173):      at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:999)
E/flutter (32173):      at com.android.bluetooth.Utils.enforceBluetoothPrivilegedPermission(Utils.java:884)
E/flutter (32173):      at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.permissionCheck(GattService.java:737)
E/flutter (32173):      at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService.writeDescriptor(GattService.java:5031)
E/flutter (32173):      at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$BluetoothGattBinder.writeDescriptor(GattService.java:1460)
E/flutter (32173):      at com.android.bluetooth.gatt.GattService$BluetoothGattBinder.writeDescriptor(GattService.java:1448)
E/flutter (32173):      at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGatt.java:1194)
E/flutter (32173):      at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1380)
E/flutter (32173):      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1311)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth HID devices, such as a gamepad, are handled by the operating system itself. You will not have access to this interface.

It therefore seems advisable to use Android's own [game controller support](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/game-controllers), such as this package: [n Gamepad](https://pub.dev/documentation/n_gamepad/)